# Laravel 5.8, CRUD when editing image didn't show up (blade)?

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-blade

I try to create edit blade to get old value from database. the title successfully appears, but the image and body (textarea) didn't appears, 
here is some code of my edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('blog.update', $post->id) }}" method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='post-form'>
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Isi</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" cols="5" class="form-control" name="body" value="{{$post->body}}"></textarea>
                    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-flat">
                <div class="image-news">
                    <span>Cover Berita</span>
                    <ul class="icons-list">
                        <li><a href="#" data-action="collapse"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="category-content">
                    <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                <img src="{{ $post->image_thumb_url ? $post->image_thumb_url : 'http://placehold.it/200x150&text=no+image' }}" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Pilih Gambar</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Ganti</span><input type="file" name='image'></span>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Hapus</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is my contoller connect to edit.blade.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    { 
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->get('title');
        // $post->excerpt = $request->get('excerpt');
        $post->body = $request->get('body');
        $post->published_at = $request->get('published_at');
        $post->category_id = $request->get('category_id');
        $post->author_id = Auth::user()->id;

        if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $image = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destination = public_path() . '/imgberita/';

            $successUploaded = $request->file('image')->move($destination, $file->getClientOriginalName());

            if($successUploaded)
            {
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $thumbnail = str_replace(".{$extension}", "_thumb.{$extension}", $image);

                Image::make($destination . '/' . $image)
                ->resize(250, 170)
                ->save($destination . '/' . $thumbnail);
            }
            $post->image = $image;
        }else{
            $post->image = 'logo.jpg';
        }
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('blog.index')->with('message', 'Berita berhasil dibuat');
    }

 public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        return view("backend.blog.edit", compact('post'));
    }
```

Can anyone help me, how to show image the right way in edit.blade.php

Comment: Please shear the `edit` method of your controller because your model will pass the view in that method and then it will pass to `update` method to store, the `store` method will use to create new entity

Comment: do you mean function?

Comment: yes I mean function but in OOP we can call them methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this line of your code please change as follow:

From:

```
<img src="{{ $post->image_thumb_url ? $post->image_thumb_url : 'http://placehold.it/200x150&text=no+image' }}" alt="...">
```

To:

```
<img src="{{ $post->imageThumb ?? 'http://placehold.it/200x150&text=no+image' }}" alt="...">
```

Then add the following function to your Post model:

```
public function imageThumb(){
    if($this->image_thumb_url){
        if(File::exists(public_path() . '/imgberita/'.$this->image_thumb_url)){
            return public_path() . '/imgberita/'.$this->image_thumb_url;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then use the function in your view like this if that image exist it will return the location if not exist it will return the null.

```
$post->imageThumb
```

If you get issue with this function just update the `public_path() . '/imgberita/'` inside the function, hope you get idea.

For `textare` you can use the `old()` function in your view:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="5" class="form-control" name="body" value="{{$post->body}}"></textarea>
```

For example like this:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="5" class="form-control" name="body"  value="{{old('body') ?? ''}}"></textarea>
```

But remember we use the `old('body')` function when we use the `validate()` and we pass the data from controller by using `->withInput()` like this:

```
return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->withInput()
    ->withErrors($validator);
```

Also you can directly pass data in your `edit.blade.php` by using `with($request)` function.

If your body is null you will get error then use the `{{$post->body ?? ''}}`.

Comment: done im use <img src="{{ $post->image_url ? $post->image_url : 'http://placehold.it/200x150&text=no+image' }}" alt="...">

Comment: public function getImageUrlAttribute($value)
  {
    $imageUrl = "";

    if ( ! is_null($this->image))
    {
      $imagePath = public_path() . "/imgberita/" . $this->image;
      if (file_exists($imagePath)) $imageUrl = asset("imgberita/" . $this->image);
    }

    return $imageUrl;
  }

Comment: how about the body?

Comment: @kuntet I will update my answer for `body textarea`

Comment: First of all i don't see your `update` function and I do not see any validation on in your `store` function - fist use the `{{$post->body ?? ''}}` in your view

Comment: If you have validation in your `update` function just add `->withInput()` to false section of your return

Comment: if($team){
            return redirect()
                ->route('teams.index')
                ->with('success','Team created successfully.');
        } else {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator);
        }

Comment: solved. <textarea rows="5" cols="5" class="form-control" name="body" value="">{{$post->body}}</textarea> thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<img src="{{ $post->image_thumb_url ? $post->image_thumb_url : 'http://placehold.it/200x150&text=no+image' }}" alt="...">
```

to

```
<img src="{{ $post->image_thumb_url ? asset('/imgberita/'.$post->image_thumb_url) : 'http://placehold.it/200x150&text=no+image' }}" alt="...">
```

OR

```
    <img src="{{ $post->image_thumb_url ? asset('public/imgberita/'.$post->image_thumb_url) : 'http://placehold.it/200x150&text=no+image' }}" alt="...">
```

Comment: whats your project running directory ?

Comment: the image have done solved, but value body still won't show